# Hibernate second level cache: Hit and miss counts are always 0

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

I am using hibernate 4.1.7 and ehcache as second level cache

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">
          org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>              
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
```

When I check miss count and hit count before and after DB calls, I get always get 0.

```
long loadEntityCount = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics("com.xys.Program").getElementCountInMemory();
    long hitCount = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics("com.xys.Program").getHitCount();
    long missCount = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics("com.xys.Program").getMissCount();
```

List patientPrograms = getProgramsForPatient( r);

```
loadEntityCount = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics("com.xyz.Program").getElementCountInMemory();
        hitCount = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics("com.xyz.Program").getHitCount();
        missCount = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getStatistics().getSecondLevelCacheStatistics("com.xyz.Program").getMissCount();
```

I was expecting non zero values for both cases and miss count goes up.

Any help?

Comment: Have you enabled statistics?
 javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode=ALL
hibernate.generate_statistics=true